# how to delete a node from firebase

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I am developing an android project with firebase. and now I want to delete a node on clicking on a button. but this error occurred and I can not solve it. I want to delete the node of 1589445758397. as I press the delete button all posts in the node post start deleting one by one and then the upper node with name Posts delete. please help me to solve it.

here's my code-

```
private void deletePostsWithImages(final String pId, String pImage) {

        ////////////////////////////
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Deleting Post");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
        /////////////////////


        StorageReference picRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(pImage);
        picRef.delete()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                        Query fQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts")
                                .orderByChild("pId").equalTo(pId);

                        fQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    ds.getRef().removeValue();
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Post deleted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


    }


    private void deletePostsWithoutImages(final String pId) {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Deleting Post");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
        Query fQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts")
                .orderByChild("pId").equalTo(pId);

        fQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ds.getRef().removeValue();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Post deleted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7nrI.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
ds.getRef().removeValue();
Toast.makeText(context, "Post deleted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

try:

```
dataSnapshot.setValue(null);
Toast.makeText(context, "Post deleted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: hello, Thanks for your response but this doesn't work for me as it can not found setValue(null) like this. please suggest something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove some specific node and you have the ID of the node then why are you listening and looping?

**Just point to the node and remove it:**

```
private void deletePostsWithoutImages(final String pId) {
.......
.......

//point to the node

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").child(pId);

//remove that node

ref.removeValue();

........

}
```

Comment: hello Mr. Hasan, Thanks for your response but that thing didn't work for me by doing this my app starts crashing. Please Suggest me something else as I'm trying very hard. If you want I can Post full code of this fragment. For your better understanding.